# How to sequence groups of async functions without nesting (jquery $.when .then)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I have groups of async functions where each group depends on the results of the previous group, but within a group the functions can execute/resolve in any order.

How can I call the groups of functions in sequence without a nesting level for each group?

```js
    function waste(secs)
    {
     var prom=$.Deferred();
     setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').append('<p>'+secs+'</p>');
            prom.resolve();
        }, secs*1000);
     return prom;
    }
    
    $.when(
     waste(5),
     waste(4)
    ).then(function(){
     $.when(
      waste(3),
      waste(2)
     ).then(function(){
      $.when(
       waste(1),
       waste(0)
      ).then(function(){
       $('body').append('<p>done</p>');
      });
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The following is what I figured out so far, but it has the kind of awkward `return $.when(` indent in each section:

```js
function waste(secs)
{
    var prom=$.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').append('<p>'+secs+'</p>');
        prom.resolve();
    }, secs*1000);
    return prom;
}
    
$.when(
    waste(5),
    waste(4)
).then(function(){
    return $.when(
        waste(3),
        waste(2)
    );
}).then(function(){
    return $.when(
        waste(1),
        waste(0)
    );
}).then(function(){
    $('body').append('<p>done</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What would be the right, best practices way to sequence groups of async functions where all the methods in a group need to finish before the next group is executed?

I guess ideally, something like this is what I wish worked:

```
$.when(
    waste(5),
    waste(4)
).when(
    waste(3),
    waste(2)
).when(
    waste(1),
    waste(0)
).then(function(){
    $('body').append('<p>done</p>');
});
```

Comment: Does `return $.when` resolve Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 technically, it does solve the nesting problem, but it seems rather cumbersome to have `).then(function(){return $.when(` between each series of function calls, and I'm not sure how it would work if a request fails, so I'm trying to find the "standards" way to do it.

Comment: See `.then(doneCallbacks, failCallbacks)` http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/#deferred-then-doneCallbacks-failCallbacks

Comment: @guest271314 yeah, I guess I was thinking that the 'whens' don't even have 'thens', but I guess you could add a then on each one and only pass it the failcallbacks

Comment: See post for one approach of adding `.fail()` , `.then(success, err)` callbacks.

Comment: Friendly reminder: Don't let the thread die a silent death.

Answer (score 3):

How about tackling the problem from a different angle: What input do you want to map to what output? Let's see if we can generalize your problem enough for this.

---

Basically you have a sequence of sets of parallel operations.

Each operation can be represented by a function and a list of arguments, waiting to be executed when the appropriate time has come. Let's name that abstraction a *callDef*:

```
[func, arg1, arg2, arg3]
```

or, for the sake of your example:

```
[waste, 5]
```

The utility to run this is simple:

```
function call(callDef) {
    return callDef[0].apply(null, callDef.slice(1));
}
```

---

Now each group of operations can be represented as a callDef *itself*, assuming we have a `callInParallel` function that takes a list of *callDefs*:

```
[callInParallel, [callDef, callDef]]
```

or

```
[ callInParallel, [[waste, 5], [waste, 4]] ],
```

The `callInParallel` function is equally simple:

```
function callInParallel(callDefs) {
    return $.when.apply($, callDefs.map(call));
}
```

---

So your entire input can be represented as a list of nested *callDefs*:

```
[
    [ callInParallel, [[waste, 5], [waste, 4]] ],
    [ callInParallel, [[waste, 3], [waste, 2]] ],
    [ callInParallel, [[waste, 1], [waste, 0]] ]
]
```

Now we can execute the leaf *callDefs* individually through `call` and each group of them in parallel through `callInParallel`.

The missing bit is a a `callInSequence` function that executes each *callDef* after the previous one has finished.

Since `callInParallel` returns a promise we can use that as a prerequisite for the execution of the next *callDef*: We need to store the result of the previous operation in an intermediate `wait` variable and chain the next operation to it through `.then()`. After that we can overwrite `wait` with the current operation, effectively preparing it for the next step.

When all steps are chained we can return an overall promise, again through `$.when`, with the overall promise not resolving before the last one, which does not resolve before on the second-to-last, and so on:

```
function callInSequence(callDefs) {
    var wait = $.Deferred().resolve();
    return $.when.apply($, callDefs.map(function (callDef) {
        return wait = wait.then(function () {
            return call(callDef);
        });
    }));
}
```

Since our abstraction allows it, we can represent the entire operation in a single *callDef*:

```
[
    callInSequence, [
        [ callInParallel, [[waste, 5], [waste, 4]] ],
        [ callInParallel, [[waste, 3], [waste, 2]] ],
        [ callInParallel, [[waste, 1], [waste, 0]] ]
    ]
]
```

---

Putting it all together:

```js
function waste(secs) {
    var result = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('body').append('<div>'+secs+'</div>');
        result.resolve('done ' + secs);
    }, secs * 1000);
    return result.promise();
}
function call(callDef) {
    return callDef[0].apply(null, callDef.slice(1));
}
function callInParallel(callDefs) {
    return $.when.apply($, callDefs.map(call));
}
function callInSequence(callDefs) {
    var wait = $.Deferred().resolve();
    return $.when.apply($, callDefs.map(function (callDef) {
        return wait = wait.then(function () {
            return call(callDef);
        });
    }));
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

var everything = [
    callInSequence, [
        [ callInParallel, [[waste, 5], [waste, 4]] ],
        [ callInParallel, [[waste, 3], [waste, 2]] ],
        [ callInParallel, [[waste, 1], [waste, 0]] ]
    ]
];

call(everything).done(function () {
    $('<hr>').appendTo('body');
    $('<pre>', {text: JSON.stringify(arguments, null, 2)}).appendTo('body');
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
$('<div>sequence has started...</div>').appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Notes:

- jQuery 1.8+ required for this code, because of changes in how Deferreds behave in 1.8.
- You can combine things differently:

  ```
  var everything = [
      callInSequence, [
          [ callInSequence, [[waste, 5], [waste, 4]] ],
          [ callInParallel, [[waste, 3], [waste, 2]] ],
          [ callInSequence, [[waste, 1], [waste, 0]] ]
      ]
  ];
  ```
- There is no handling for the `thisArg` in the above, every function will be called against the global object (`window`). I leave implementing that as an exercise. There two ways to do it, one is using `.bind()`, the other one is extending the definition of `callDef`.

Comment: Did you used to program in lisp?!   I really like this answer.  I think something very direct like that should be implemented natively in  javascript or jquery, to eliminate the awkward lamda functions.

Comment: I imagine something like:
$.async([waste,5],[waste,4]).async([waste,3],[waste,2]);

or even

$.async('waste(5)','waste(4)').async('waste(3)','waste(2)'); 

or perhaps natively

await {
  waste(5);
  waste(4);
}

Comment: No, I've never programmed in Lisp. :) As you can see, a lot is possible with plain JS already, not everything needs a native language construct.

Answer (score 0):

> not sure how it would work if a request fails,

```js
function waste(secs) {
    var prom = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('body').append('<p>' + secs + '</p>');
      prom.resolve();
    }, secs * 1000);
    return prom.promise();
  }
  // define error handler
var err = function err(e) {
  console.log(e)
};

$.when(
waste(5),
waste(4)
).then(function() {
  return $.when(
    waste(3),
    waste(2)
  ).fail(err);
}, err).then(function() {
  return $.when(
    waste(1),
    waste(0)
  ).fail(err);
}, err).then(function() {
  $('body').append('<p>done</p>');
}, err);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the description of how to add the fail conditions, but do you in general believe that this a straightforward and good way to handle sequencing groups of async function calls?

Comment: @AwokeKnowing  Yes, straightforward. "good" can be subjective; could be composed various ways ; as long as author is comfortable with implementation and expected results returned , perhaps "good" enough for author what matters ? Viewing without any description would appear that each `$.when` is distinct "group" of functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `$.when` is equivalent to `Promise.all`. In that case, what you're doing is correct. I think all you can really do to improve the aesthetic is join some of your lines:

```
$.when(waste(5),waste(4))
  .then(function() { return $.when(waste(3), waste(2)); })
  .then(function() { return $.when(waste(1), waste(0)); })
  .then(function(){
    $('body').append('<p>done</p>');
  }, errorHandler);
```

Is there a reason you're using jQuery for this? This can be done natively with Promises:

```
function append(secs) {
  return Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('body').append('<p>'+secs+'</p>');
      resolve();
    }, !isNaN(secs) && secs*1000);
  });
}

Promise.all([append(5), append(4)])
  .then(function() { return Promise.all([append(3), append(2)]); })
  .then(function() { return Promise.all([append(1), append(0)]); })
  .then(function() { return append('done'); }, errorHandler);
```